# Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tes1.php on line 19

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm sorry if this question is may already similar to others question. I certainly success to make a connection to database. I'll try to show all the databases that I have. But when I tried with my code, i got this error.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SHOW DATABASES;');
$names = array($sql);
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($value);
    echo $row.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: What was your error? Please update your question with it so that we can help you.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\tes1.php on line 19
Array ,

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SHOW DATABASES;');
$row = array();
while ($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {        
    print_r ($row) ;       
}
```

Comment: thanks for advance it works, how about to show array index, that code showed all the array index with [0]

Comment: @AlKahfiBalkoiniP Do this instead:    echo $row[0] ."<br>";

Comment: how about if i use foreach not while,

foreach ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql) as $key => $value) {
 print_r($value);
}


it shown only the first array, how to show all the array ? thank you

Comment: You cannot use foreach in that case.

Comment: @AlKahfiBalkoiniP I have edited my answer based on what you want.